# Overwriting nested serializer's create method throws TypeError: create() got multiple values for keyword argument

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to send data to my API. My data structure is nested. So I am trying to overwrite the create method following the docs and SO.

When sending data it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'graph'
```

My data structure looks like this:

```
{
        "project": "project1",
        "name": "Graph1",
        "description": "Graph belongs to Projekt1",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Node1 of Graph 1",
                "graph": 3
            }
        ]
    }
```

Her is what I am trying in my serializer (which is pretty standard I assume):

```
class GraphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    nodes = NodeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:

        model   = Graph
        fields  = ('project',
                   'name',
                   'description',
                   'nodes',
                   )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        nodes_data = validated_data.pop('nodes')
        graph = Graph.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print(graph)
        for node_data in nodes_data:
            Node.objects.create(graph=graph,**node_data)

        return graph
```

The error is in the for loop. When I debug though and print `graph`it give me back just one Graph (Graph1). So I don't understand why I should get a multiple values error.

Here is more info if needed:

```
Node serializer

class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model  = Node
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'graph',
                  )
```

```
My models 

class Graph(models.Model):
    project         = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def nodes(self):
        return self.node_set.all()

class Node(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    graph           = models.ForeignKey(Graph, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

PS: I also have another model which is almost the same as Node model. It is also attached to a Graph. So in the end I would like to send data with a double nested serializer. I guess I will ask this in a separate question, but if someone can point me to the right direction on how to do this I would be also very happy. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you are sending the `graph=graph` keyword argument explicitly and there is another `graph` keyword argument inside `node_data`. I am assuming that from `NodeSerializer`. So, you need to remove `graph` from `NodeSerializer` fields to make it work or make the `graph` field read-only. Like this

```
class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model  = Node
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'graph',
                  )

       read_only_fields = ('graph',)
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic ruddra, that was indeed the problem. Both suggested solutions work perfectly fine. Thank you my friend!